# html5shiv.js and respond.js without Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

```html
 <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Whenever I search for these scripts on the internet they are always connected with Bootstrap 3. Should I use them in any responsive website using HTML5?

Comment: We wouldn't be able to tell you, it depends on what you're doing. `html5shiv` is a Javascript workaround to add support for HTML5 elements in older browsers. `Respond.js` is a polyfill to add support for CSS3 media queries in older browsers. So if you need to support older browsers, then yes, you should use them. If not, then don't.